# 80 character limit with ClangFormat works with comments starting with @ but not \

Tags: qt-creator, clang-format

I have a `.clang-format` with `ColumnLimit: '80'`. When I write doxygen blocks for functions like the following, they get neatly wrapped at 80 characters:

```
    /**
     * @brief Writes out the 80-byte header (in binary STL) for the STL representation of some geometry.
     * @param[out] fileStream - The file to write the header to
     */
```

Becomes:

```
    /**
     * @brief Writes out the 80-byte header (in binary STL) for the STL
     * representation of some geometry.
     * @param[out] fileStream - The file to write the header to
     */
```

But if I do the same thing with `\` instead of `@` it no longer automatically wraps if it goes over:

```
    /**
     * \brief Writes out the 80-byte header (in binary STL) for the STL representation of some geometry.
     * \param[out] fileStream - The file to write the header to
     */
```

I should note that the *following* lines after a `\`, or just stray comment blocks work fine. IE, if I do

```
/**
 * Here is a really long comment that is greater than 80 characters, notice how it gets wrapped?
 */
```

It becomes:

```
/**
 * Here is a really long comment that is greater than 80 characters, notice
 * how it gets wrapped?
 */
```

Why does this happen?

Clang version: 7.0.1

My IDE is **QTCreator**, version 4.7.2. I have it set to reformat files on saving them, which it does for everything. (Except comment lines starting with `\`)

Comment: You mention here doxygen, I think this is not a doxygen problem but a problem in the IDE you use, as the last 2 code snippets suggest some changes in source code. Question is is this a doxygen problem, if so please specify the doxygen version used and the changes in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) you used compared to the default Doxyfile (for newer doxygen versions: `doxygen -x`). Please add the information to the body of the question.

Comment: Ok. I've removed the doxygen tag, added what IDE I am using - QTCreator.

Comment: I think the problem might be that doxygen used `\` and `@` as command starters, but Qt only used `@`, so inside QtCreator I could think of some different behavior, though actually it should not be dependent of the used characters. This said the `\` character is of course a bit of a different character (often used as escape character).

Comment: So QTCreator sees ```@``` as a new comment, and wraps it, but sees ```\``` as some kind of escape character and does not let clang-format touch it? Is there a fix for that?

Comment: It is just a wild guess from my side (looks like I had some problems with the backslash in my previous comment as well), someone knowing, the internals of, QtCreator or another user might be shine a light on it. I just had a look at the QDoc about writing documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoc-guide-writing.html) and here they use the backslash as a command starter (I just checked the doxygen documentation and it looks like I was mistaken about the @ and backslash), so even weirder but maybe it is intentional that this happen so that documentation that needs on one line isn't split.

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a very reasonable guess. A little unfortunate, but good to know.